# How to make a REAL sleep() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know there are many methods like setTimeout, but I just want a REAL one.

I'm using JavaScript to write a compiler, and I have to find out a way to implement the sleep() function.
I know that buggy loop way, it's not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: By real, you mean? What are you design reqs?

Comment: Why would you need to sleep() while compiling code?

Comment: This is a bad idea if you're planning to run this code in a browser and your goal isn't to freeze the UI.

Comment: I'm writing a compiler, and the original language has a sleep() function.

Comment: Is Javascript your development language for the compiler or your target environment? In other words, are you just writing the compiler in Javascript, or will the compiler generate Javascript as its "machine language" to be run in a browser or other JS runtime?

Comment: @XhackerLiu whats the original specification for `sleep()` ?

Comment: @paxdiablo the compiler generate Javascript as its "machine language" to be run in a browser. I'm writing a simple script language to create some graphic.

Comment: @Raynos sleep(x): pause for x ms, and then execute the rest code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the answers above i gather that you want a sleep function that doesnt freeze the browser and doesnt use setTimeout.

Good luck with that, javascript is single threaded. **This is NOT possible**

Comment: Single threaded javascript === Cannot sleep thread without blocking.

Comment: @Xhacker he just said javscript is single-threaded, which means it has absolutely no conception of threads or concurrency whatsoever. :D

Answer (score 4):

You can't, at least in most browser implementations. You'll have to make your compiler work around that. [StratifiedJS](http://onilabs.com/stratifiedjs) does something similar.

I'll add some more detail. This, obviously, is not the best way to implement a sleep function, but since you said you're doing a simple drawing language, I'll just go with this:

Imagine you have some code like this:

```
drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);
sleep(1000);
drawLine(5, 6, 7, 8);
```

That could be converted into this by breaking up all the `sleep`s:

```
var pieces;
function advance() {
    pieces.shift()();
}
pieces=[
    function() {
        drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);
        setTimeout(advance, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        drawLine(5, 6, 7, 8);
    }
];
advance();
```

Or, if your language is more complex than that, you could do this with more complexity for the compiler (this is the obvious solution):

```
drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);
setTimeout(function() {
    drawLine(5, 6, 7, 8);
}, 1000);
```

Again, this may not be applicable if your language gets very complex, but it may be helpful as a starting point.

Comment: So you mean I can't implement the sleep() function?

Comment: @Xhacker Liu: That's what I'm saying. You can, however, make your compiler convert the synchronous code into asynchronous code, therefore avoiding the issue.

Comment: Why does everyone still think that every Javascript program runs in a browser? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, I'm aware that there are other implementations. That's why I said "at least in most browser implementations".

Comment: icktoofay's solution is correct. You're in charge of the compiler in this scenario so I would have it generate continuations and implement sleeping via `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to take a block loop

```
while(condition) {
    // do something
    sleep(x);
}
```

and turn it into

```
function foo(values) {
    if(condition) {
         // do something
         setTimeout(function() {
            foo(values); 
         }, x);
    }
}
foo(someValue);
```

Also you can take a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // do something
    sleep(x);
}
```

and turn it into

```
function foo(i) {
    // do something
    i++;
    if (i < n) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            foo(i);
        }, x);
    }
}
foo(0);
```

Basically turn your loops into recursive calls then replace your sleeps with asynchrous recursive calls.

In a loop you need to physically block to slow down the step. In recursion you can delay the call to the next recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

The only **real and reasonable** way to implement `sleep()` in JavaScript (at least in the browser environment) is to use `setTimeout`. Just process your compiled instructions one by one, and then take a break when you encounter the sleep instruction:

```
function resume() {
    while (instructions.length) {
        var instruction = instructions.shift();

        switch (instruction.opcode) {
        case "foo":
            doFoo(instruction.operands);
            break;
        case "bar":
            doBar(instruction.operands);
            break;
        case "sleep":
            doSleep(instruction.operands);
            return; // pause running
        }
    }
}

function doSleep(operands) {
    setTimeout(resume, operands[0]);
}

var instructions = compile(source);
resume();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call a function in X milliseconds you can use `setTimeout`, but you knew that.

You can hack things together using Date and `getTime`.

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var exitTime = now.getTime() + milliseconds;
    while (true) {
        now = new Date();
        if (now.getTime() > exitTime)
        return;
    }
}
```

**[stolen from here](http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2007/12/javascript-sleep-function.html)**

**However** you are totally freezing the current thread for a possible long period of time. I think you would basically be stopping all javscript action on the page for X milliseconds, which would be **very** annoying if the time is greater than 300ms.

**[there's some pretty good analysis of javscript sleep methods here.](http://www.devcheater.com/)**

If you give us a little more context we can probably be more helpful. Sleep is usually used in multithreaded scenarios in other languages, which is exactly why is was left out of javascript. What features do you need in your compiler? :D

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i want...It's a CPU burner.

Comment: @Xhacker what DO you want? At this point all we can do is guess. Why do you need the sleep? What are your requirements? :D

Comment: I want to design a simple script language, the main feature is to draw basic graphic. With a sleep function, it can make some simple animation.

Comment: @XhackerLiu why use `sleep` instead of `delay(recursiveCallback)`. Don't treat javascript like C !

Comment: @Raynos I just want to convert another script language to javascript.

Comment: @Raynos For example, a snippet like:
while (i > 3):
    drawline(); sleep(10);
How to compile to JS?