# Sleep function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sleep

I'm new to **JavaScript** from Java, and I'm trying to implement a `sleep(millis)` function. Basically I need to make a request to an endpoint, and if it returns an error, wait a while and make the request again...

I've found JavaScript's `setTimeout()` function, but it has a strange (for me) behaviour, because it seems that the code is still running, and I don't want to do anything but wait...

After a little research I've found this function [**here**](http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/):

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

With this function I achieve exactly what I want, but I understand it may not be the proper way to do it and I didn't find any other solutions like this... So, I'd like to know, in your opinion, is this:

- A perfectly valid solution?
- A not too bad workaround?
- Just painful to your eyes?

Comment: I'd much rather use `setTimeout` to schedule my runs than eat up cpu resources looping like that.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: You can do this in proper and javascript way. Make ajax request to endpoint and on getting response, handle it like this. If error, give same function as `setTimeout`'s arg. otherwise `clearTimeout` with your timeoutId.

Answer (score 1):

Well, opinions will vary. I can understand you though, JavaScript doesn't have a real sleep function like Java or any other language (like Perl, Bash, PHP, etc)

http://devcheater.com/ shows multiple variations, but also check out these Stackoverflow topics:

[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep?rq=1)
[What's the best way to implement a sleep function JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845972/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-sleep-function-javascript)
[How to make a REAL sleep() in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858414/how-to-make-a-real-sleep-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this code is that is stays busy all the time until the code finishes. This may cause a warning dialog in many browsers, and it also slows the page down.

[image: The dialog]

Here I would still prefer to use the `setTimeout` function. The syntax is quite simple:

```
setTimeout("codeToBeExecuted()", milliseconds);
```

You can simplify it by saving the code after sleeping in a function, and passing the needed data in global variables or like this:

```
setTimeout('whenDone(' + numericData + ', "' + stringData + '")', milliseconds);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcr8u/%20JSFiddle)

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't like `setTimeout`, but basically, that's what you need to do.

```
function myFunc() {
    // Do the work
    setTimeout(myFunc, sleepInterval);
}
```

(Assuming you're trying to create a repeating schedule, if not, call your other function rather than `myFunc` again).

You can (and probably should) of course add some termination logic as well.

Then start your work with `myFunc()`. You could also use `setInterval`, but it can cause some problems if your intervals start to overlap.

Regarding your solution, I select option 3...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `sleep` function in Javascript, and you should consider using [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call the next operation. I certainly would not burn cycles in a `for` loop. But if you must wrap it in a function named `sleep` then here is an example to give you an idea.

```
function sleep(callBack, milliSecs) {
    setTimeout(callBack, milliSecs);
}


function first() {
    console.log("first");
}

function second() {
    console.log("second");
}

first();
sleep(second, 5000);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kHxCv/)